# How to share an instance of a singleton class between two windows

Tags: singleton, electron, instance, share

I am working with small electron application, and I want to ask one small question.

I need to share a singleton class instance between different two windows of my app.
“Share” means instance which has each class is the same and variables of the instance are the same.

I used affinity parameter in the BrowserWindow() constructor to run two windows in the same renderer process. I suppose if the two windows run in the same process, the two windows share the instance. But actually, the instance and the values of the instance are different.

Is this a correct behavior?
1.If so, could you tell me another way to share an instance between two windows?
2.If not, is this a bug? Or do I need to set another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

affinity option exposes control to chromimum's process model (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11484 / https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models) and none of chromium's process model allows share hosted page's context between. Running two site in single process doesn't necessarily mean two hosted sites shares context, especially it exposes whole security concerns around.

There is no such thing for singleton in electron, at least from out of box supported way via electron's supported api surface. Though it's not true sharing, sync via ipc is nearly only way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.    

I understand that the context is not shared even if the two windows are running in the same process.  

I am sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I would like you to tell me about context. Does context mean the instance or the variable held within that instance?

Answer (score 0):

i use `window.open()` method to create new BrowserWindow, when use this method, you can paas your javascript singleton class by `window`

`render-process`

```js
 const modal = window.open(filePath, 'xxx');
 modal.window.singletonClass = window.singletonClass;
```

`main process`

```js
 mainWindow.webContents.on('new-window', ()=> {});
```